# How to inject rx.subjects.Subject<T, T> with Dagger

Tags: rx-java, dagger

I have a `rx.subjects.Subject` in my `Presenter`, `PublishSubject.java` to be precise. Cause I'm following DI pattern for my objects creation and reference collaborators using their supertypes, I need to inject `Subject` but `PublishSubject` (besides the latest being `final` isn't mockable).

In order to differentiate between different `Subject` implementations, I've introduced a Qualified: `@Publish`.

`@Qualifier @Retention(RUNTIME) public @interface Publish { }`

Declared it a `Module`:

```
@Module(// ...)
public class MyModule {

  @Provides @Publish Subject provideSubject() {
    return PublishSubject.create();
  }

}
```

And pointed in the `Presenter`:

```
public class Presenter {
  Subject<Void, Void> mSubject;
  @Inject public Presenter(@Publish Subject subject) {
    mSubject = subject;
  }
}
```

So in the end `Dagger` (first version) complains it can't find `Subject<Void, Void>`. So might be the general question could be - how to inject a generic interface?

Comment: Which line it complaints? I assume injected constructor?

Comment: First Dagger isn't clear about it's errors, but it is definitely because of dependency declared in the constructor.

Comment: Can you change parameter type and return of the provides method to `Subject<Void, Void>`?

Comment: Subject is parameterized, and you aren't listing any of your parameterized types. Is your IDE or compiler showing warnings or errors aboutt that? In any case, beware that Guice, Dagger, and Dagger2 all use the full parameterized type as a key for injection, so a binding for `Subject` may not fulfill a binding for `Subject<Void, Void>` or `Subject<Integer, Integer>`.

Comment: This is actually the problem, so I'm curious how to declare a Subject dependency so it can satisfy any Subject<T, T>. No warnings from IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrapper class, holding your subject.

```
@Provides MySubscribtion provideMySubscription() {
    return new MySubscribtion(PublishSubject.create());
}

private class MySubscribtion {
    private final Subject<String, String> subscription;

    public MySubscribtion(Subject<String, String> subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
    }

    public Subject<String, String> get() {
        return subscription;
    }
}
```